# .vimrc function - How to call "normal" mode keypress of equals (=) key

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a function that I can call from a command, that will allow me to re-set all open panes to equal size. I started with this:

```
command Equal execute "normal! <C-w>="
```

Which allows me to call

```
:Equal
```

Which works the way I would expect it to. However, I need to add a little more functionality to this (an if statement, etc), so I need to declare it as a function. However, I cannot figure out how to call the "equals sign" key from within my function. Here is what I have:

```
command Equal call EqualizePanes()

function! EqualizePanes()
  execute "normal! <C-w>="
endfunction
```

I know that my function declaration and method of calling it is correct, because I have replaced the contents of my function with something simple, like "echo foobar", which works as expected. However, as it stands, when I call `:Equal`, nothing happens. I have tried other things like:

```
command Equal call EqualizePanes()

function! EqualizePanes()
   normal <C-w>=
endfunction
```

as well, without any luck. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `normal` doesn't parse special character sequences like `<C-w>`. So escape

```
command Equal call EqualizePanes()

function! EqualizePanes()
  execute "normal! \<C-w>="
endfunction
```

- [`:help expr-quote`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-quote)
- [`:h execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexe)
- [`:h normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Note that there's a special `:wincmd` Ex command that you can use instead of `:normal`; this avoids the `:execute` that is normally necessary to process the `\<C-w>` notation:

```
command Equal wincmd =
```